# How to fill some properties in model after evaluation of IQueryable in OData?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, odata

I'm using OData with Entity Framework. Let's assume that I have following models and controller method:

```
public class Model1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Field2 { get; set; }
    public int FieldFromOtherService { get; set; }
    public Model2 Model2 { get; set; } // Navigation Property
    public int Model2Id { get; set; }
}

public class Model2
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Field { get; set; }
}


[HttpGet, EnableQuery]
public IQueryable<Model1> Get()
{
    return modelRepository.List();
}
```

`Model1` has property `FieldFromOtherService` that is not taken from DB - it is retrieved from other service. I need a way to fill this property after applying OData top, skip, expand and select clause.

Is there a way to accomplish that? I've tried to make a wrapper to `IQueryable` and call action after evaluation but it crash when query is more complicated.

Comment: Instead of `EnableQuery` use `ODataQueryOptions<Model1>` as a parameter in your action. then, do `options.Apply(modelRepository.List()` that will give you the list of your objects, and then you can `foreach` or otherwise set the required property

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I manage to accomplish my goals with @zaitsman suggestion. It was harder then I thought because OData adds wrappers that are not accessible (classes `SelectAllAndExpand`, `SelectAll`, `SelectSomeAndInheritance`, `SelectSome`). When expand is used, it is necessary to extract DTO from the wrapper. My code looks more or less like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult Get(ODataQueryOptions<Model1> options)
{
    var result = modelRepository.List();
    Action<ICollection<Model1>> postAction = collection => { Console.WriteLine("Post Action"); };
    return ApplyOdataOptionsAndCallPostAction(result, options, postAction);
}

private IHttpActionResult ApplyOdataOptionsAndCallPostAction<T>(
    IQueryable<T> baseQuery, 
    ODataQueryOptions<T> options, 
    Action<ICollection<T>> postAction)
    where T : class
{
    var queryable = options.ApplyTo(baseQuery);
    var itemType = queryable.GetType().GetGenericArguments().First();
    var evaluatedQuery = ToTypedList(queryable, itemType);

    var dtos = ExtractAllDtoObjects<T>(evaluatedQuery).ToList();
    postAction(dtos)

    return Ok(evaluatedQuery, evaluatedQuery.GetType());
}

private static IList ToTypedList(IEnumerable self, Type innerType)
{
    var methodInfo = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod(nameof(Enumerable.ToList));
    var genericMethod = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(innerType);
    return genericMethod.Invoke(null, new object[]
    {
        self
    }) as IList;
}

private IEnumerable<T> ExtractAllDtoObjects<T>(IEnumerable enumerable)
    where T : class
{
    foreach (var item in enumerable)
    {
        if (item is T typetItem)
        {
            yield return typetItem;
        }
        else
        {
            var result = TryExtractTFromWrapper<T>(item);
            if (result != null)
            {
                yield return result;
            }
        }
    }
}

private static T TryExtractTFromWrapper<T>(object item)
    where T : class
{
    if (item is ISelectExpandWrapper wrapper)
    {
        var property = item.GetType().GetProperty("Instance");
        var instance = property.GetValue(item);
        if (instance is T val)
        {
            return val;
        }
    }

    return null;
}

private IHttpActionResult Ok(object content, Type type)
{
    var resultType = typeof(OkNegotiatedContentResult<>).MakeGenericType(type);
    return Activator.CreateInstance(resultType, content, this) as IHttpActionResult;
}
```